# v2.0 Protocols - SPAs using the implicit flow Microsoft

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

Well, I have an angular.js client and a WebApi Server. I want to use OAuth 2.0 authorization of Microsoft and I just can't understand how I should get the answer from the http get request to the /authorize endpoint and why when I try to make the request I get a CORS problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check [Authorize access to web applications using OAuth 2.0 and Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/). It worked for me along with [simple-oauth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-oauth2) library.

Make sure that you totally understand what exactly authorization endpoind you need. I've started with Oauth 2.0, but then I realized that new [v2.0 endpoint](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview/) is better way for me with [this tutorial for angular](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-angular-node/#sign-users-in) and [workflow explanation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oidc/):

> In the past, an app developer who wanted to support both Microsoft 
>   accounts and Azure Active Directory was required to integrate with two
>   separate systems. We've now introduced a new authentication API
>   version that enables you to sign in users in with both types of
>   accounts using the Azure AD system. This converged authentication
>   system is known as the v2.0 endpoint. With the v2.0 endpoint, one
>   simple integration allows you to reach an audience that spans millions
>   of users with both personal and work/school accounts.

And keep in mind that Live APIs are deprecated:

> The Live Connect APIs are deprecated. We recommend that you use the 
>   Outlook REST APIs to build your solutions. This will extend your reach
>   to Outlook.com users and Office 365 enterprise customers. Although the
>   Live Connect APIs will be supported in Outlook.com for the short term,
>   existing Live Connect API solutions might stop working without
>   advanced notice. If your app is using IMAP with OAuth 2.0, it will
>   continue to work, but our REST APIs are the primary APIs for building
>   apps that connect to Outlook.com and Office 365. Read the article on
>   how you can take advantage of the Outlook REST APIs.